# React.js App Built With Gulp Is Not Showing Up

Tags: reactjs, gulp

I'm having issues launching a React.js app built with Gulp.

I ran `npm install` even `npm update`, but when I go to the browser, I do not see the app, but instead I see a blank screen.

Also, I noticed that `gulp` build produced a blank index.html file.

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Default</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link href="./app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="registration-form"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html> -->
```

Please advise.

[image: localhost]

[image: terminal printout]

Comment: Your entire HTML is commented out... (`<!-- ... -->`)

Comment: Ops! That's an obvious one